# Can javascript MSE play segmented mp4 from the middle?

Tags: javascript, websocket, ffmpeg, mp4, media-source

in my current project i have a video stream that ffmpeg encodes to a segmented mp4. that encoded data is piped into an application that sends that data to whomever connects to that application through a websocket. when a client connects i make sure to send the ftyp and the moov boxes first and then send the most recent segments recieved from ffmpeg.

on the client side i just pass all binary data from the websocket to MSE.

The problem i am facing is that this works if the client is connected from the very start and gets all the fragments that ffmpeg pipes out, but it does not work if the client connects in after ffmpeg sends its first few fragments.

My question is:
Is it possible for MSE to play a fragmented mp4 from the middle when it is also provided the init segments?

If it is possible then how would that need to be implemented?

if it isnt possible then what format would allow me to stream live video over a websocket?

Comment: You have to move the `currentTime` of the `video` DOM element to `video.buffered.end(0)` time, so the player can play. Otherwise, the browser tries to play from the start (and will wait indefinitely for segments with that time to arrive).

Comment: thanks @PabloMontilla for the answer. this fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for MSE to play a fragmented mp4 from
> the middle when it is also provided the init segments?

Yes, This is exactly what fragmented (segmented) mp4 was designed to do

> If it is possible then how would that need to be implemented?

The way you describe your implementation is correct. Send init fragment, followed by most recent AV fragment. Which means you have a different problem or a bug in your implementation.